# Dotfuscator 5.3 (from Visual Studio 15.3) doesn't obfuscate .NETStandard 2.0 .DLL

Tags: .net-core, dotfuscator

When running the latest Dotfuscator CE (comes with VS 2017, the latest updates and .NET Core 2.0 SDK installed), I'm getting errors like this when processing .NET Standard 2.0 .DLL:

**Couldn't load external type because its assembly can't be found: System.Security.SecurityRuleSet,netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51**

What can I do? I thought maybe Dotfuscator does not find .NET Core 2.0 dlls so I added "c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib" path to DEVPATH and activated developmentMode in machine.config but it didn't help much. In the logs, it was clear that Dotfuscator now "sees" DEVPATH folder and the error message became slightly different but it's still there.

**Couldn't load external type because its assembly can't be found: System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream,netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51**

It's working fine if I process .NET Core 1.1 .DLL (.NET Standard 1.3). Only .NET Core 2.0 fails.

Dotfuscator CE doesn't seem to have any public forum (they provide support for their commercial version only), that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, the quickest solution is probably to copy the `netstandard.dll` file from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\netstandard.library\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\ref` to the same location as your input assembly.

*Disclaimer, I work for PreEmptive Solutions*

Comment: Thank you for reply but this didn't change anything. Still see this in the logs (it keeps searching for System.dll for some reason):

LOG: Processing DEVPATH.
LOG: Searching DEVPATH : c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.dll
LOG: Searching DEVPATH : c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.exe

Comment: OK, I removed DEVPATH completely (because I added DEVPATH to debug this issue) and voila, now your advice did work as expected! I got a new issue now (with Microsoft.Win32.Registry) but I'm sure I'll work it around somehow. Thanks again!

Comment: I ran into same issue but with .net core 2, what is work around for it?

Comment: In the end, it didn't work out. Dotfuscator injects mscorlib dependency, an attempt to remove it by ildasming and then ilasming fails. I reached to the point where ilasm crashes with "RangeChecks instrumentation code detected an out of range array access" and that's the end of story. Seems I'll have to try another obfuscator.